# Replacing text using regular expression with variable text?

Tags: c#, regex

Lets say I have some text with lots of instances of word "Find", which I want to replace it with text like "Replace1","Replace2","Replace3", etc. The number is the occurrence count of "Find" in the text.
How to do it in the most effective way in C#, I already know the loop way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `MatchEvaluator` can do this:

```
string input = "FindbcFinddefFind", pattern = "Find";
int i = 1;
string replaced = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match => "REPLACE" + i++);
```

Note that the `match` variable also has access to the `Match` etc. With C# 2.0 you'll need to use an anonymous method rather than a lambda (but same effect) - to show both this and the `Match`:

```
string input = "FindbcFinddefFind", pattern = "Find";
int i = 1;
string replaced = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, delegate(Match match)
{
    string s = match.Value.ToUpper() + i;
    i++;
    return s;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the overload that takes a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) and provide the custom replacement string inside the delegate implementation, which would allow you to do all the replacements in one pass.

For example:

```
var str = "aabbccddeeffcccgghhcccciijjcccckkcc";
var regex = new Regex("cc");
var pos = 0;
var result = regex.Replace(str, m => { pos++; return "Replace" + pos; });
```